# dom-repeat not updating when path from firebase-query changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-polymer

I'm using the `firebase-query` element which is working at first attempt in setting the path.

```html
<firebase-query id="queryTag"
                    path="[[_getProductTagsURL(productData)]]"
                    data="{{tags}}"></firebase-query>
```

I then use the data by using dom-repeat:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tags}}" index-as="index" id="tags">
      <paper-item>
        <paper-item-body two-line>
          <div><span>[[item.$key]]</span></div>
          <div secondary><span>[[item.description]]</span></div>
        </paper-item-body>
        <paper-icon-button icon="delete" on-click="_deleteItem"></paper-icon-button>
      </paper-item>
</template>
```

And here's the function that returns the URL path for the `firebase-query` element:

```js
_getProductTagsURL: function(data) {
        console.log('/users/' + this.user.uid + '/products/' + data.key + '/tags');
        return '/users/' + this.user.uid + '/products/' + data.key + '/tags';
      }
```

Every time the path changes it logs the correct path. When the path of firebase-query is set for the first time, the `dom-repeat` displays the correct data, but when changed it doesn't display anything.

Comment: For future reference, the path of the firebase-query needs to be set as null: this.$.query.path = null; before changing it to another path and the data will populate :)